# How to access multiple level nested object in json with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, tastypie

Im currently playing around with Ember js and have run into a problem when trying to access nested json objects that are multiple levels deep.

For example, i get a json response:

```
{
   -questions: [
       -{
           -title:"What is 2+2?",
           -answers:{
                meta: { },
                objects: [
                    -{
                        -body: "it is 4"
                        -author:{
                             first_name: "John",
                             last_name: "Jones"
                     }
                 ]
            },
           -author:{
                first_name: "Joe",
                last_name: "Bloggs"
            }
   }
 ]
```

}

At the moment i have mapped author in ember data just fine but i am not able to map objects that are deeper than 1 level i.e. answer objects. 
My models for a question and a user:

```
QPAC.Question = DS.Model.extend({
     title: DS.attr('string'),
     body: DS.attr('string'),
     author: DS.belongsTo('QPAC.User')
});

QPAC.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I have set the map on my adapter:

```
Adapter.map('QPAC.Question', {
    author: {embedded: 'load', key: 'author'}
});
```

Any pointers on how to map the answer objects (there can be multiple) inside my question model?

I am using the DjangoTastypieAdapter btw

Thanks!